# Couldn't locate MessageTracer database (at path /var/log/DiagnosticMessages)

Tags: macos, mac

Whenever I open "About this Mac" > "More Info..." and navigate to logs there is an entry with the following content. Any idea what I can do about it?

> /usr/bin/pmset -g log:
>
> Description: Power Management logs
>
> Size:    77 bytes
>
> Last Modified:   5/19/11 11:26 PM
>
> Recent Contents: Couldn't locate MessageTracer database (at path /var/log/DiagnosticMessages)

I am on a MBP with OS X 10.6.7

TIA

Comment: Are you logged in on a non-administrator account?

Comment: @Bas I coudn't see any difference even if I logged in as an admin user.

Comment: Do you get any result when you do "sudo pmset -g log" on the command line? (you should see some sort of log of course)

Comment: @karmatic: did you find out the problem?